# PHP cannot share session between two scripts w/ register_globals=on and session_save_path defined

Tags: php, session, scripting, shared

I have two scripts on the same domain. 
www.xxx.com/first/
www.xxx.com/second/

I have register_globals=on, I've checked the spelling multiple times. I've checked session_save_path() and they both are working on the same directory.

I even tried setting session_save_path to a new directory just in case.

Each script is accessing a session independently. If I set the value of a session variable in one script, it stays. If I set the value of it in the other script it stays. Neither of the scripts are updating the other, so they must be writing their own sessions. I'm using the same browser without any security.

Any ideas to what would make these talk?

Thanks!

**UPDATE!
Found out that one of the scripts was defining a session_name variable. Make sure that these are the same.
Thanks for all your help anyways!**

Comment: Save the info in a database, flat file...

Comment: @JohnConde The data might be user-dependent.

Comment: Still can be stored in a db or flat file

Comment: I think the bigger problem here is having [register globals on](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Comment: What is the path of the cookie holding the session id? If you are setting that cookie with `setcookie()` under www.xxx.com/first/ and don't explicitly specify '/' as path, it won't be available in every sub directory, only under /first/.